# How to check excel file open by external process

Tags: c#, excel

How to check excel file open by external process if open how to close it in c#. How to update file in open condition?
For example, data.xlsx is my excel file.
I have try this.

```
Process[] excelProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
foreach (Process process in excelProcess)
{
    if (process.MainWindowTitle.ToLower() == "data" || process.MainWindowTitle == "Microsoft Excel - data")
    {
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file inside try catch and handle the close in finally block

```
    try
    {
        fStream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        //File is being used
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fStream != null)
            fStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to update excel file even it is open by other process?

Comment: try to use `file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);`

Comment: I understood what you want to say but i'm curious to know it.